# Does derived pushforward commute with exterior powers?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, derived-functors

Let $q : C \times X \rightarrow C$ be the projection, where $C$ is a curve and $X$ is a smooth projective variety $X$. Consider the associated derived pushforward $q_* : D^b(X \times C) \rightarrow D^b(C)$. Let $E$ be a sheaf on $X \times C$.

My question is: when is it true that the $k$-th exterior power commutes with derived pushforward, i.e. when is it true that $\Lambda^k q_*(E) \cong q_*(\Lambda^k E)$?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? Does "rarely" satisfy you?

Comment: @Sasha Yes, having thought about it for a while I think this will only happen in rather specific cases; not as general as I was hoping for - thanks.